# Error 400 at a particular line of code in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code:

```
'Declare variables
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim rv As Range 'rv = row value
Dim wsn As String 'wsn = worksheet name
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rws As Worksheet 'record sheet worksheet
Dim ri As Long 'row index used for rv
'Set record workbook and worksheet
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set rws = wb.Worksheets("Record sheet")

'refer to concatenate column
Dim lastr As Long
Dim r As Range
lastr = rws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
Set r = rws.Range(Cells(2, 7), Cells(lastr, 7))
```

But when it reaches this code:

```
Set r = rws.Range(Cells(2, 7), Cells(lastr, 7))
```

I get a 400 error. I've spent ages trying to figure out whats causing it and i don't know what I'm doing wrong. I've tested my rws variable and it works by going to the correct worksheet when running a "rws.select" test.

Comment: What value has `lastr` when stopped on error? I mean, moving the cursor over it...

Comment: Try Dimming r as a variant, and then do r = Array(rws.Range(Cells(2, 7), Cells(lastr, 7))) and then have a look at what was captured in the locals window.

Comment: lastr = 64 when error occurs

Comment: After doing r = Array(rws.Range(Cells(2, 7), Cells(lastr, 7))) , im now getting run-time error'1004':Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Comment: Update: it only works if i put rws.select before running those final few codes. i dont know why though

Comment: the `Cells` were defaulting to the active sheet you can't have a single range across multiple sheets.

Comment: Always qualify your objects like you did qualify the worksheet with `wb.`, you need to qualify the ranges, cells, rows, columns, and whatnot with `rws.`: `rws.Rows.Count` and `rws.Cells(...)`

Comment: Thank you, ill look more into qualifying variables